# Rewind ifSteam in C++

Tags: c++

I'm aware this has been asked a few time before and I read the threads related to it but the solutions there didn't work for me.

```
ifstream myFile;

myFile.open("largefile.txt");

    if (myFile.is_open())
        {
            while (!myFile.eof( ))  //step through each line until end of file
            {
                myFile>> str;
                if(str.size() < 5){
                    amount++;
                }
            }
        }

    myFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

if (myFile.is_open())
        {
            for(int i=0; i != random_integer; i++)  //step through each line until random line reached
            {
                myFile>> str;
                if(i == random_integer-1){
                cout << "\n";
                cout << str;
                cout << "\n";
                cout << str.size();
                }
            }
        }
        myFile.close();
```

I read that using EOF in the while statement was a bad idea, whats the alternative? And how can I rewind for the second loop as seekg isn't working out, I don't want to have to close the file and open again, and the file is to large to read into an array really?

TIA, I'm sure this is an easy fix I'm just very new to C++.

Comment: if steam, then there is probably some fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myFile >> str` is not guaranteed to work just because you checked for end of file, because that is a flag only set when EOF has been read, not when it is about to be read.

Instead you should do:

`while( myFile >> str )`

You also need to clear your stream before you use it again (with seekg). One of the unfortunate things about streams is that they hold state as flags and they can trip you up if you are not careful.

`myFile.clear();`

then continue.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of testing `eof()` (which doesn't work correctly), you should 
just verify that each input has worked, by using the stream in a boolean
context:

```
while ( myFile >> str ) {
    //  ...
}
```

Once it has failed, of course, the stream is in a failed state, which
must be reset before any further operations are allowed:

```
myFile.clear();
myFile.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::beg );
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very clear explanation (and it works). The 0 in seekg is that the pointer to the start of the file? Why is the second argument not just ios_base::beg what does the std:: bit do?

Comment: @EricBanderhide It ensures that the compiler can find the symbol.  All of the symbols in the standard library (except macros) are in the namespace `std`.  If you don't have a `using namespace std;` or a `using std::ios_base;` somewhere, then the compiler shouldn't be able to find `ios_base`.